# CiviMail - delivered and opened are always the same

Tags: civimail

For the report for a mailing from CiviMail, delviered and opened counts are always the same. Our client reports that for a number of mailings, the number opened always equals the number delivered. They don't think this is very realistic ...

I sent a test mailing to two different email addresses (both mine), viewed only one of them, but both showed as delivered *and* as opened.

CiviCRM 4.5.4 on Drupal.

Comment: Are you able to test if this still happens in 4.6? This is currently supported and will be the new LTS version.